# CRM 2011 Marketing List Members - Add but not remove

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm-ribbon-workbench

I want users to be able to select the 'Manage Members' button but not the 'Remove from Marketing List' button.

I have tried to do this through security role permissions unsuccessfully.

I have also tried finding the Ribbon through Ribbon workbench in order to disable the button but cannot find the ribbon that is associated with the Marketing List Members frame.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create a “dummy” RemoveMemberFromList role and write a plugin on the RemoveMemberList message. If the user has this role throw an exception.

Here is how to retrieve a user role from a plugin https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18a05216-ea17-4f2d-b416-e11a5555ffda/how-to-retrive-current-user-role-in-plugin-in-crm-2011?forum=crm

Comment: Not like a "dummy" role, just a Remove members roles, like a copy from the original role so we don't have an empty role.

Comment: The plugin approach seems to be the only way.  CRM 2011 apparently does not expose the ribbons of default intersect entities for editing: https://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/forums/155731-general/suggestions/3574361-button-on-ribbon-of-related-n-n-entity.